# How to update an App on Apple App store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I have upload an App on App store.Now I have make some UI changes in the App.Now again I want it to UPDATE the App on the Apple App store.I don't want to change its version.Just need to update the APP.What is the procedure to do this .Do I have to follow the full old steps which i do for upload an App.Or is there any other option.Any tutorial will be helpful.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In iTunesConnect select your App. Click on Add Version.
 Add the Details and then click in the upper right on Prepare for Upload.

Then you can archive your Build in Xcode and just submitt it like you have done it with the initial build.

Comment: That's Right ! :) But don't forget to update the version of the App on XCode before submitting it.

Comment: Sorry But I don't know Why My Uploaded App is not showing in the iTunes Connect.When I first login with my Apple Account and then click in iTunes Connect and then go into the Manage Your Apps Option.It is showing that there are no Apps.But My App is on the Apple App store .I checked this

Comment: Then it must be on another account

Comment: Another Account ..Sorry but I don't have any other Apple Account .I have submit the App from the Account which i have only...No Other Account I have .Also AS i uploaded from this Account .Then it should be there only.Rite?

Comment: That is weird... Try to look at See all in the right top. Otherwise I would contact Apple Support

Answer (score 0):

first of all i want to tell that if you want to update your app then you have to change your version
for example current version is 1.0 and now u upadte so you have to change it as 1.1,1.4 whatever 
in short without changing in version you can't submitt your app so simply change your version and then follow the procedure that you previously upload your app